# Parse to Firebase Database Migration

Tags: ios, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Still my app uses Parse for storing user details for my existing application, since Parse announced that shutdown date for their service, we planned to use Firebase,

Shall we import parse users into my Firebase framework, if yes please suggest way to migrate parse to Firebase.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios

Comment: Thanks @Frank, Will it possible to retrieve all users from parse to my firebase db?

Comment: why would you do this, @VetriVel?  everyone has just clicked to move parse.com hosting to bacck4app.com hosting.  it's identical

Comment: Yes @Joe Blow, we moved into back4app server. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not easy to answer on stack overflow completely since it highly depends on what your data is like and what your source code is like.  The first question I would have is why are you not using the [suggested migration path which is using open source parse-server and mongodb](https://parse.com/migration)?

If you do actually switch to firebase, then Frank's link is a great place to start.  Switching from parse to firebase will not be a 5 minute process however, since the backends are completely different (although they seem very similar on the surface).

You can retrieve all your data from parse, including the user collection by going to the parse dashboard - App Settings - Export App Data.  This will export JSON files of all your classes.  You can find a way to import this into Firebase, but this will be done offline and then (if your app is live), the data will not be synchronized between the 2 backends.

The [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios) suggests 2 approaches for this:

> Migrate Your Data
>
> After you decide how to structure your data in Firebase, you need to
>   plan how to handle the period during which your app needs to write to
>   both databases. Your choices are:
>
> Background Sync
>
> In this scenario, you have two versions of the app: the old version
>   that uses Parse and a new version that uses Firebase. Syncs between
>   the two databases are handled by Parse Cloud Code (Parse to Firebase),
>   with your code listening to changes on Firebase and syncing those
>   changes with Parse. Before you can start using the new version, you
>   must:
>
> Convert your existing Parse Data to the new Firebase structure, and
>   write it to the Firebase Realtime Database. Write Parse Cloud Code
>   functions that use the Firebase REST API to write to the Firebase
>   Realtime Database changes made in the Parse Data by old clients. Write
>   and deploy code that listens to changes on Firebase and syncs them to
>   the Parse database. This scenario ensures a clean separation of old
>   and new code, and keeps the clients simple. The challenges of this
>   scenario are handling big datasets in the initial export, and ensuring
>   that the bidirectional sync doesn't generate infinite recursion.
>
> Double Write
>
> In this scenario, you write a new version of the app that uses both
>   Firebase and Parse, using Parse Cloud Code to sync changes made by old
>   clients from the Parse Data to the Firebase Realtime Database. When
>   enough people have migrated from the Parse-only version of the app,
>   you can remove the Parse code from the double write version.
>
> This scenario doesn't require any server side code. Its disadvantages
>   are that data that is not accessed is not migrated, and that the size
>   of your app is increased by the usage of both SDKs.

Comment: "This question is not easy to answer" - right, the two things are **totally conceptually different**.  Basically *you cannot* move from Parse to Firebase.  What you do is just move from Parse to AWS, use a free instance on AWS of their nosql database.   **But why would you do all this? just click to swap to back4app.  It "is" parse, the URL just changed.**